# Webmin no longer works - connection rejected

Tags: server, webmin

I've had webmin installed on my 12.04 server and everything has been fine until recently. Now when I navigate to https:// myip:10000 I get a message saying the connection attempt is rejected. The last thing I did was set up a cron job to start utorrent webUI.

I tried reinstalling but no change. When I check with netstat I see a webmin entrance on port 10000. I've also reset the iptables and allowed everything. I'm at a loss as to what to do now.

Answer (score 1):

I've just experienced the same thing.

It looks like uTorrent was preventing webmin from starting up successfully. I tried various things to get uTorrent to start up on reboot alongside webmin but to no avail.

Eventually I got webmin working by removing the `utorrent.conf` file like so: `sudo rm /etc/init/utorrent.conf` and installed Transmission torrent client instead (which worked perfectly with no conflicts with webmin).

Answer (score 1):

Webmin uses `port 10000` as we can see in `netstat -nap`, but if you are running utserver first of running webmin service it will also bind the `port 10000` to it, because of a service of device pairing of utserver.

To avoid this bind another port in webmin at `Webmin > Webmin Configuration > Ports and Addresses`

Or in other hand you can disable the service of pairing in utserver
`Settings > Advanced > Search for net.discoverable and turn it to false > Save Settings > Restart utserver service (service utserver restart)`

Check with netstat -nap if there is a bind of 127.0.0.1:10000 to utserver, doing that it will not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't use Ubuntu, the same thing appears to happen in other OS's like OpenSuse for example.  I found that stopping the instance of utserver and then starting Webmin, then restarting utserver resolved my issue.  Problem is that when you restart, you have the same issue again.  It appears that utserver takes control of port 10000 for some reason.  I guess another option would be to run webmin on a different port?  I havent tried that yet....

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a 2 year old post, but I came across it when looking for a solution for this exact same problem.

I tried making changes to upstart scripts and/or writing my own without any luck. In the end I got what I wanted (booting webmin first to occupy port 10000 and utserver after to learn that port 10000 is taken and choose another port).

Webmin - System - Bootup and Shutdown - Module Config

Tick "Yes" to "Allow selection of individual runlevels?".

Webmin - System - Bootup and Shutdown - webmin

In your default runlevel (cursive print), change the value of 99 to e.g. 79.

Reboot.